# Send directory as an attachment with email C#

Tags: c#, email, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to send a directory through email?

I'm using this method to send a log file to my email, but I want to send a directory which would be the save game folder of the game I'm working on in Unity.
I'm using this as a bug report, as I need to get the game save files to find bugs.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

public void email_send()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("your mail@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
    mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:/textfile.txt");
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your mail@gmail.com", "your password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);

}
```

If it's not possible to send a directory what is the workaround to achieve that?

Comment: Create a zip with that directory and send zip

Comment: You could zip the directory and send it

Comment: You could send each file in the directory as separate attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You may zip the complete directory contents and send the archive file as attachment.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: just zip it and send as file.

Answer (score 0):

The **GZip** Class of .NET might just be what you want! [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx)
The Compression Snippet right off of there

```
public static void Compress(DirectoryInfo directorySelected)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo fileToCompress in directorySelected.GetFiles())
            {
                using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
                {
                    if ((File.GetAttributes(fileToCompress.FullName) & 
                       FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden & fileToCompress.Extension != ".gz")
                    {
                        using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz"))
                        {
                            using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, 
                               CompressionMode.Compress))
                            {
                                originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);

                            }
                        }
                        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(directoryPath + "\\" + fileToCompress.Name + ".gz");
                        Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.",
                        fileToCompress.Name, fileToCompress.Length.ToString(), info.Length.ToString());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

You could also use the standard **Zipping** class from here [ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx)